# Getting error and don't know how to solve it - an argument of 'float[]' type was used but a 'series float' is expected

Tags: syntax-error, pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, technical-indicator

I am getting this error on compliation for Tradingview Pine script 5

````
# Cannot call 'operator *' with argument 'expr0'='call 'operator SQBR' (float[])'. An argument of 'float[]' type was used but a 'series float' is expected.

I know the issue is in this 2 lines because i am multipling array to a value which is not correct and I need to convert float to series but I dont know what and how to do that:

```
# forward_error += autocorrelation[i] * array.get(ar_coefficients, i - iter)
# backward_error += autocorrelation[i - iter] * array.get(ar_coefficients, i)
```

```
// Autoregressive function using Burg method
    source = input.source(close, "Source")
    order = input.int(2, "Order")
    lookback = input.int(100, "Lookback", minval = 2)

// Step 1: Calculate Autocorrelation Function (ACF)
    autocorrelation = array.new_float(lookback)
    for lag = 0 to lookback - 1
        correlation = ta.correlation(close, source[lag], lengthBB)
        array.push(autocorrelation, correlation)

// Step 2: Initialize Coefficients
    ar_coefficients = array.new_float(order + 1)
    array.push(ar_coefficients, 1.0) // Initialize first coefficient as 1

// Step 3: Iterative Calculation (Burg algorithm)
    for iter = 1 to order
        forward_error = 1.0
        backward_error = -1.0
    
    for i = iter to lookback - 1
        forward_error += autocorrelation[i] * array.get(ar_coefficients, i - iter)
        backward_error += autocorrelation[i - iter] * array.get(ar_coefficients, i)
    
    // Avoid division by zero
    if backward_error != 0.0
        reflection_coefficient = -2.0 * forward_error / backward_error
        // Update coefficients using Burg recursion formula
        temp_coefficients = array.new_float(order + 1)
        array.push(temp_coefficients, 1.0) // First coefficient remains 1
        
        for i = 1 to iter
            coefficient = array.get(ar_coefficients, i) + reflection_coefficient *    array.get(ar_coefficients, iter - i + 1)
            array.push(temp_coefficients, coefficient)
        
        ar_coefficients := temp_coefficients

// Calculate autoregressive values
    hlc3_series = (hlc3)
    autoregressive_values = array.new_float(lookback)
    for i = 0 to lookback - 1
    value = 0.0
    for j = 1 to order
        // Perform element-wise multiplication and addition
        value += array.get(ar_coefficients, j) * hlc3_series[i - j]
    array.push(autoregressive_values, value)

// Plot autoregressive values
    for i = 0 to lookback - 1
    // Plot individual autocorrelation values
    plot(array.get(autocorrelation, i), color=color.purple, title="Autocorrelation Values")
````

```
I tried to change the Float to series but no matter what Syntax I am typing I always get more errors
How to convert float array to series?`
```

Answer (score 0):

`autocorrelation` is an array. You cannot do `autocorrelation[i]` to access its elements.

You need to use the `array.get()` function for that as you do in other places.